# Open big data files (.txt or no extension & >3GB) on Jupyter Notebook and turn into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have downloaded data from online (huge datasets of more than 3.5 GB) in an unusual file format (file without extension like .txt or .xcl).

I can't read it/save it/open it/convert it to a Pandas dataframe in Python (Jupyter notebook) because:

1) It is very large (3.5 GB)

2) It has no extension so I can't use things like read_csv or read_excel or ... I also can't add an extension.

Please help me see and start playing around with my data.

Here are 4 cells that didn't output any data:

1)

```
filename = "gps_20161001"
GPS_2016_1001 = open(filename, "r")
print (GPS_2016_1001)
```

output is: TextIOWrapper encode bla bla bla

2)

```
data = pd.read_csv('gps_20161001', header = None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "etc."]
print (data)
```

NO OUTPUT

3)

```
Cars = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\UROP 2019\gps_20161001')
df = pd.DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Brand', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

NO OUTPUT

4)

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open(Day1.tar.gz, "r:")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

NO OUTPUT (Note that Day1.tar.gz is the zip that contains the file gps after I compress it with 7-zip file manager)

I honestly just want to save my huge code into a simple dataframe (like an excel sheet with a million rows I can look at) and then play around with the columns.

Comment: For 1), have you tried GPS_2016_1001.read()? Also, are you saying you don't know the format the data is in? Because if so it could be anything...

Comment: Hello thank you for your engagement. I have tried read it still wouldnt let me read. Also the format is "File" which is weird. I tried converting it to csv by adding .csv in the end but that "cheat" couldn't let me open it either. Same for .txt with notepad

Comment: I think you need to find out exactly what format the file is in. The information should be on the site you downloaded the data from, otherwise there's nothing we can do with the data.

Comment: The file has a zip file: (After compression)
Data format: tar.gz
Data volume: 7.9G (After compression)